# hunspell tag with missing characters and not ordered correctly

Tags: hunspell

As per the official documentation the TRY parameter can look something like this...

```
TRY esianrtolcdugmphbyfvkwzESIANRTOLCDUGMPHBYFVKWZ'
```

In this example - j, q and x capital and small letters (jqx JQX) are missing.

Is there any specific reason that the 3 characters were not included in the list? Instead of writing a, b, c, d the list starts with e, s, i. Is there any reason behind the ordering?

Answer (score 0):

as per [17 (ever so slightly) weird facts about the most popular dictionary format](https://zverok.space/blog/2021-03-16-spellchecking-dictionaries.html) written by zverok, the author of [spylls](https://github.com/zverok/spylls), the TRY option describes the language’s alphabet (**sorted by letter frequency**); This should imply that J, Q and X letters are not present in the language.

A more detailed explanation is this one, from an [old italian documentation project](https://web.archive.org/web/20110217060149/http://linguistico.sourceforge.net/pages/creadiz/file_.aff.html):

TRY: This instruction indicates the order of characters to use in suggestions for correcting misspelled words. The characters on the left should be the most probable, while those on the right should be the least probable.